# Need to add custom values in Azure DevOps under Planning

Tags: azure-devops

[image]

[image]

How could I add custom values? I need to add custom values under the Planning section in work item for environments. I have tried to look in organizational settings, but I cannot really find the place where i can add such things. I have tried to Google this, but could not really found any relevant information. Any ideas? If you need more info, just ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe those are stored in Project Settings->Boards->Project Configuration, then click "Areas" or "Iterations" beneath the word "Boards".

[image]